# Mapping of Number and varchar2

Tags: sql, oracle

I have 2 tables like

```
table 1

a:varchar2(100)

100,200,300,530
125.325.526.254
125.254.325.100
100.563.100.254
278.100.215.214
125.214.685.258

table 2(number)

b:

100
200
300
400
524
```

My question is, if I give `100` from 2nd table and that query should display all occurrences of 100 in the 1st table

For example. I give 100 and the output should be

```
100,200,300,530
125.254.325.100
100.563.100.254
278.100.215.214
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SQL> WITH DATA1 AS(
  2  SELECT '100,200,300,530' STR FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  3  SELECT '125.325.526.254' STR FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  4  SELECT '125.254.325.100' str from dual union all
  5  SELECT '100.563.100.254' STR FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  6  SELECT '278.100.215.214' STR FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  7  SELECT '125.214.685.258' STR FROM DUAL),
  8  DATA2 AS(
  9  SELECT 100 VAL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
 10  SELECT 200 val from dual union all
 11  SELECT 300 VAL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
 12  SELECT 400 VAL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
 13  SELECT 524  VAL FROM DUAL),
 14  DATA3 AS(SELECT VAL FROM DATA2 WHERE VAL = 100)
 15  SELECT A.*
 16     FROM DATA1 A, DATA3 B
 17    WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(STR,TO_CHAR(B.VAL))
 18  /

STR
---------------
100,200,300,530
125.254.325.100
100.563.100.254
278.100.215.214
```

where, **data1 is your first table having string, data2 is your second table having numbers. Just replace the with clause of data1 and data2 with your tables.**

**Update : Regarding design flaw and normalization**

From a design point of view, your table design violates `normalization`. You should not store multiple values in a single column, and use proper datatype to avoid `implicit data conversions`. In your case, you should have different columns for values like `'100,200,300,530'`. Just imagine, when your table is normalized the column value `'100,200,300,530'` would look like :

```
col1 col2 col3 col4 col5
---- ---- ---- ---- ----
1    100  200  300  530
```

where, col1 is the primary key and col2,col3,col4 and col5 are NUMBER data types.

Similarly, your second table should be `referencing` the first table. The number column becomes a `foreign key`, thus you implement `referential integrity`.

Comment: Thanks Mr.Lalit kumar.Your query is very close to my requirement and its works exactly.

Comment: Is there a need for regular expressions here? Wouldn't a simple LIKE be sufficient? Your answer could also be improved by explaining why this is not a good data model.

Comment: Added design flaw and normalization, hope it provides better understanding.

Answer (score -1):

Your query will be something like below :

```
select * from


 (select convert(a,varchar) as A from table1) T

where T.A like '%100%'
```

Comment: `CONVERT()` in Oracle converts strings between character sets; `CAST()` would be more appropriate

Comment: What has `CONVERT` function to do anything here?

Comment: Avoiding implicit conversion is a good thing @Lalit... Ángel just seems to be more used to SQL Server.

Comment: Yep , Its tagged for SQL hence i written like that

Comment: Of course @Ben. And that's the reason I have used `TO_CHAR`in my answer. Never rely on implicit conversions. I didn't know this answer was intended for SQL Server, no idea.